# Как запустить ASP .NET Core проект на сервере с Ubuntu 16.04 и Apach?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

Всем привет. Долго искал информацию по этому поводу, но так и не справился с этой задачей.
Может кто знает, как можно запустить веб-приложение ASP .NET Core на сервере, чтобы его "видели" все в интернете?

Comment: В официальной документации [все прекрасно расписано](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache).

Comment: Самый "лучший" ответ. Спасибо "огромное"

Comment: Может мой вопрос предполагает, что я не смог сделать то, что было представлено в документации, а?

Comment: Ваш вопрос предполагает то что написано в вопросе. Мы не телепаты чтобы догадываться какую работу вы проделали и что не получилось.

Comment: я уже справился со всем самостоятельно. А вопрос чётко излагает суть - как залить ASP NET Core проект на сервер с Ubuntu и Apach.

Comment: [Прежде чем задать вопрос, убедитесь, что вы выполнили тщательный поиск ответа. Поделитесь результатом вашего поиска и расскажите, что вы нашли и почему найденные ответы вас не устроили. Это продемонстрирует вашу способность думать самостоятельно, поможет избежать повторяющихся очевидных ответов и, самое важное, увеличит шансы на получение точного ответа!](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена, для этого достаточно использовать пакет dotnet:

```
dotnet run -c Release
```

или

```
dotnet run
```